# AWS Cron to run a lambda once every day monday to friday?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am currently using the cron 'cron(0 9 ? * MON-FRI *)' in AWS cloudwatch but it seems to run it continuous every minutes for that hour, what am I doing wrong?

I wanted it to run every weekday (mon-fri) at 9am on the dot.

Comment: Your expression seems correct

Answer (score 0):

I would try `0 9 * * 1-5`

You can debug it here for instance: https://crontab.guru/#0_9_*_*_1-5

Comment: it says it is  a invalid expression

Answer (score 0):

You should use -> `0 9 ? * MON-FRI *`

[image]